# How do I split this delimited text in to key and value using a Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've been landed with a column of data that looks like this:

```
1[::]One[::]2[::]Two[::]3[::]Three
```

How can I split this in to a Dictionary in C#? To give:

```
1,"One"
2,"Two"
3,"Three"
```

Is a Regex the right approach?

I've got this far `\d+\[::]` but am uncertain what to do next

Comment: Is this the only possible data-layout, or can there be just `1[::]One` and data upto `15[::]fifteen`? Do you have control over the data while it's generated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't really need regex; just a delimiter split using the [`String.Split(String[], ...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var str = "1[::]One[::]2[::]Two[::]3[::]Three";
var parts = str.Split(new [] { "[::]" }, int.MaxValue, StringSplitOptions.None);
// parts is an array that contains: "1", "One", "2", "Two", "3", "Three"

var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i += 2)
    dict.Add(int.Parse(parts[i]), parts[i + 1]);
```

Comment: About 5mins after I posted the question I realised that my battle with a Regex was futile and that going down this route would make more sense. Thanks for affirming what my jet lagged brain finally realised was a better route! (And saving me from someone's code)

Answer (score 3):

This works.  I tested it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "1[::]One[::]2[::]Two[::]3[::]Three";

            string pattern = @"(?'key'[^\[]+)\[::\](?'value'[^\[]+)(\[::\])?";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            Dictionary<int, string> dict = matches.Cast<Match>().GroupBy(x => x.Groups["key"].Value, y => y.Groups["value"].Value)
                .ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x.Key), y => y.FirstOrDefault()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a regex is an overkill in this situation, you could use a simple string delimiter as follows:

```
string s = "1[::]One[::]2[::]Two[::]3[::]Three";
        string[] splitted = s.Split(new string[] { "[::]" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i%2 == 0)
            {
                dic[int.Parse(splitted[i])] = splitted[i + 1];
                i++;
            }                
        }
```

Comment: This is much more confusing than the answer given by @Douglas. When possible, you want to avoid altering the iterator variable in multiple places. Also, the modulo check is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
(\d+)\[::\]([a-zA-Z]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is fine. If you're going to use the split method (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx), understand that your regular expression is a [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter). Therefore, you need to make your regular expression whatever separates your entries; IE [::]

Another thing to note to is that in regular expressions [ and ] are actually special characters, so to use them literally you'll need a forward-slash to mark them as literals (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html). However, c# will complain because \[ is not a recognized escape sequence, therefore, make the string itself a literal with the '@' marker. This will make the string literal to c# (so it will ignore escapes) but still allow the regular expression to identify the escape sequence for its purposes.

In short, in order to have `[::]` as a delimiter in our regular expression, we actually need to enter `@"\[::\]"`

You can place your input string through the Regex.Split function, which will give you an array of strings. The regex.Split documentation I linked above offers several examples which should help you understand how to use it. So long as you are certain that the data is formatted correctly, you can sequentially enter the data into your dictionary using some kind of loop.